# Angularjs $http request caching on browser back button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

Here's my code.

```
$scope.init = function () {
            $scope.urlParam = $location.search();
            if ($scope.urlParam.token == undefined || $scope.urlParam.id == undefined) {
                $scope.is_start = false;
                alert("您没有权限投票");
            } else {
                $http.get('/vote/validate_querystring?token=' + $scope.urlParam.token + "&id=" + $scope.urlParam.id)
                    .success(function (response) {
                        if (response.status == 3) {
                            $scope.is_start = false;
                            alert("您没有权限投票");
                        } else if (response.status == 4) {
                            $scope.is_start = false;
                            alert("您已完成投票");
                        } else {
                            $http.get('/vote/r_vote_setting')
                                .success(function (response) {
                                    if (response.status == 1) {
                                        $scope.is_start = false;
                                        alert("投票尚未开始");
                                    } else {
                                        $scope.is_start = true;
                                        $scope.voteData = response.data;
                                    }
                                });
                        }
                    })
            }
        };
```

I put this function in `ng-init` so it will be invoked every time the page is loaded.

As you can see, there are **two** `$http.get` in this function. The problem is when I hit the **back button** to go back to this page, `$http.get('/vote/validate_querystring?token=')` would be loaded from browser cache while  `$http.get('/vote/r_vote_setting')` makes a new request to the server. I found this from chrome console.

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/vote/validate_querystring?token=202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70&id=1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from disk cache)
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Request URL:http://localhost:8080/vote/r_vote_setting
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

I want to know why this happens and how to make them both send request to the server rather than cache when hitting back button.

Comment: Should responses to those requests *ever* be cached? If not, solve it at the server level by marking them as uncacheable.

Comment: I am using tomcat as server. How can I mark them as uncacheable?

Comment: Refer to the Tomcat documentation and search for how to make documents uncacheable (basically, it's a couple of caching-related headers).

Comment: Thanks. I've already solved it using js

Answer (score 3):

You can  use cache: false option of $http.

```
$http.get('/vote/validate_querystring?token=' + $scope.urlParam.token + "&id=" + $scope.urlParam.id,cache: false);
```

Use $httpProvider to set caching false

```
myModule.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    //initialize get if not there
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};    
    }    

    // Answer edited to include suggestions from comments
    // because previous version of code introduced browser-related errors

    //disable IE ajax request caching
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT';
    // extra
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks. The second one works but the first one does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can also include a time parameter to the call, that would every call unique, thus avoid unwanted caching for only that specific call instead having to mess with $http default settings and potentially affect every other calls on the page

```js
$http.get({
  url: sampleUrl,
  method: 'GET',
  params: {
    time: new Date()
  }
}).error(function (err) {
  console.log('Error encountered: ' + err);
}).success(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```